# How to loop through the whole iterator

Tags: python, keras, iterator

So I created a iterator while training my model

```
train_iterator = datagen.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=64)
```

Now I want to get all the values from it.Like:
`batchX, batchY = train_iterator.next()`

will bring the first set of values.Similary I want all the values of the iterator being stored in a list or a numpy array.Is there any command for that

Comment: "all the values of the iterator being stored in a list" is simply `list(train_iterator)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for batch_x, batch_y in train_iterator:
    print (batch_x.shape, batch_y.shape)
```